# Bootstrap in Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Can someone tell me how can i use only bootstrap grid (from https://bootstrap-vue.org/) in vue project not other packages.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Vue from 'vue'

import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'

createApp(App).use(router).use(BootstrapVue).mount('#app')
```

Comment: What is your goal? Size reduction of the output?

Comment: I need it to make responsive layout.

Comment: Bootstrap is responsive by default. So you can just borrow from their examples and you'll be good.

Comment: By default npm bootstrap installing tons of not needed packages because of this i need only grid system.

Comment: Then don't use bootstrap-vue, use bootstrap directly, you import what you want in your sass

Comment: Can you write any example?